# Are methodological questions concerning Crowdsourcing within the scope of CV?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, reopen-closed, references, machine-learning

Recently, I posted two questions about Crowdsourcing on CV. The first [one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/248129/general-reference-for-crowdsourcing) asking for a general reference got upvoted, while the [second](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/247648/references-for-good-practice-in-crowdsourcing) specifically asking for a more specific reference concerning different experimental design decisions got closed as off-topic. However, quite a few commented that it appears to be on topic to them.

For me this is quite frustrating. Is crowdsourcing on topic or not? I am pretty sure it should be, because it becomes more and more important for ML, on ML conferences there are numerous papers on the topic, and the "experiment-design" tag on CV has about 800 questions.

If you disagree, please give solid reasons. If not, please consider re-opening my second thread.

Comment: There are currently 4 reopen votes for your 2nd Q so it's almost reopened. Having said that, I struggle to see any difference between your two questions. They seem the same to me.

Comment: @amoeba The first one ask for a really high-level and broad introduction text book (something like "Introduction for crowdsourcing for machine learners") while the second one asks for something like a research paper on these very technical issues.

Comment: "So, is there some general reference (for example a textbook or a comprehensive journal article) on how a crowdsourcing task should be designed from a research point of view?" vs "So my questions is do you know any kind of reference (preferably research papers) discussing what may count as good-practice in crowdsourcing" does not strike me as two sufficiently different questions. If both were open right now, I would probably be inclined to vote to close one as a duplicate of another.

Comment: Agreed. I rephrased the first questions to "So, is there some general reference on how to get started with crowdsourcing from a research point of view, something like a general introduction?" for clarification.

Answer (score 5):

Methodological questions concerning crowdsourcing and machine learning are on-topic on Cross Validated SE, but they can't be:

- duplicate
- unclear.
- too broad.
- primarily opinion-based.

Questions which ask for references are not off-topic, but depending on how it is asked some users can consider it 'too broad'. So, always try to be the most specific as possible about the request.

The following CV meta post has additional hints: 
[Question about recommended readings](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2428/question-about-recommended-readings/2429#2429).